# sonarqube: update/refresh existing issue assignments?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

we use LDAP authentication with sonarqube 5.6.

i understand that SQ can only assign issues to users who previously logged in.

now, once issues are created...
is there a way to force SQ to update existing issue assignments automatically with users who logged after issues creation?

Comment: You've barely given your group post a chance to be answered

Comment: That is not possible. On which criteria would you select the issues to be updated ?

Comment: Criteria would be all "Not assigned" issues